# Text in Graphic when typed in looks different in different computers?

Tags: fonts, typography, resolution

I don't understand why this occurs.

I have to go to my old laptop to enter text into Mspaint so that it looks good. Below is a graphic I insert into my medium.com articles. Note the smooth text.
[image]
Now if I grab that same graphic using mspaint in my new laptop, erase the text and type it in again, the text is noticeable pixelated:
[image]
Now, of course, I realize they're different machines with different resolutions. The old laptop has a recommended resolution of 1366 x 768, and the newer smaller laptop has a recommended resolution of 3200 x 1800.
That's way I thought simply changing the resolution in the new laptop to 1366 x 768 when entering such text would do the trick, but no.

[image]

It's subtle at times, but then inserting the graphic into medium.com in this case, the difference is readily apparent. The text looks...well...chunky. Below, for example, I retyped 'Decode' on my new machine at the same resolution, but it's noticeable different than the other when posted on medium.com.
[image]

I write a number of articles on a popular platform. I literally have to go to my old laptop if I want to enter some 'nice looking' text in a graphic. I don't want to have to do that. What's going on?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE. I think your problem is related to your system settings and not really a graphic design question, so I'll vote to close it. Have you checked your font smoothing settings? Find the *Performance Settings* (google it - they are well hidden) and see if *Smooth edges of screen fonts* is checked.

Comment: I agree with @Wolff here. It probably has something to do with your settings, either in the software, or on your system. What you are seeing is the difference between anti-aliased text, and text with anti-aliasing switched off.  [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/MRo4Umv)

Comment: anti-aliasing! I would have never thought. Thanks. I'll look into it.